# generic method does not compile in java

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I am studying generic methods, i just come to this code, and I  can not seem to figure out why the following line of code does not compile

```
public static T genMethod(T t) {
        return t; 
}
```

Comment: It's not generic. The error message should tell you that it can't resolve the symbol T. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: If `T` is not a type you've imported, then you should declare it as a _type parameter_ `<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `<T>` in the method signature:

```
public static <T> T genMethod(T t) {
    return t; 
}
```

For reference, the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: please explain, i got  the solution before but i need explanation

Comment: @TheScientificMethod I posted a link to the tutorial about generics in the first comment under your question. Apply The Rational Method: click the link, and read the tutorial.

Comment: @JBNizet why I need to put that, the return type is matching with with type of object i am returning

Comment: Because that's what tells the compiler that T is not an actual concrete type, i.e. a class whose real name is T, but the generic type of the method. Without the <T>, the method is not generic, and the compiler is thus looking for a class named T, hence the error message you get.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, please include this as answer, it does explain very well.